# Output to CSV changing datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I have a csv file with a column called reference_id. The values in reference id are 15 characters long, so something like '162473985649957'. When I open the CSV file, excel has changed the datatype to General and the numbers are something like '1.62474E+14'. To fix this in excel, I change the column type to Number and remove the decimals and it displays the correct value. I should add, it only does this in CSV file, if I output to xlsx, it works fine. PRoblem is, the file has to be csv.

Is there a way to fix this using python? I'm trying to automate a process. I have tried using the following to convert it to a string. It works in the sense that is converts the column to a string, but it still shows up incorrectly in the csv file.

```
df['reference_id'] = df['reference_id'].astype(str)
df.to_csv(r'Prev Day Branch Transaction Mems.csv')
```

Thanks

Comment: It's still the full number in the CSV, isn't it? Excel is just a way to _view_ the csv file. As long as the underlying data is correct (open the file with notepad), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> When I open the CSV file, excel has changed the data

This is an Excel problem. You can't fix how Excel decides to interpret your CSV. (You can work around some issues by using the text import format, but that's cumbersome.)

Either use XLS/XLSX files when working with Excel, or use eg. Gnumeric our something other that doesn't wantonly mangle your data.